# C implementation of Matlab interp1 function (linear interpolation)

Tags: c, matlab, linear-interpolation

Do you know any C implementation of the Matlab interp1 function (just 'linear' one)? I know one for [Java](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2986650/implementation-of-interp1-function-of-matlab-in-j2me).

Comment: Why was this question closed? I found the best answer (the one that corrected the indexing bugs) very useful, even if I was not looking for a C++ implementation. I could translate it to other languages easily.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have implemented this linear interpolation myself (some of it is written in Spanish, sorry). The function called **encuentraValorMasProximo** just finds the nearest value (elementoMasProximo) and index (indiceEnVector) to another one (xx[i]), in an array (xD).

```
void interp1(int *x, int x_tam, double *y, int *xx, int xx_tam, double *yy)
{
double *dx, *dy, *slope, *intercept, *elementoMasProximo, *xD;
int i, *indiceEnVector;

dx=(double *)calloc(x_tam-1,sizeof(double));
dy=(double *)calloc(x_tam-1,sizeof(double));
slope=(double *)calloc(x_tam-1,sizeof(double));
intercept=(double *)calloc(x_tam-1,sizeof(double));
indiceEnVector=(int *) malloc(sizeof(int));
elementoMasProximo=(double *) malloc(sizeof(double));
xD=(double *)calloc(x_tam,sizeof(double));

for(i=0;i<x_tam;i++){
    xD[i]=x[i];
}

for(i = 0; i < x_tam; i++){
    if(i<x_tam-1){
        dx[i] = x[i + 1] - x[i];
        dy[i] = y[i + 1] - y[i];
        slope[i] = dy[i] / dx[i];
        intercept[i] = y[i] - x[i] * slope[i];
    }else{
        dx[i]=dx[i-1];
        dy[i]=dy[i-1];
        slope[i]=slope[i-1];
        intercept[i]=intercept[i-1];
    }
}

for (i = 0; i < xx_tam; i++) {
    encuentraValorMasProximo(xx[i], xD, x_tam, x_tam, elementoMasProximo, indiceEnVector);
    yy[i]=slope[*indiceEnVector] * xx[i] + intercept[*indiceEnVector];
}
}
```

The **test** function could be:

```
void main(){

int x_tam, xx_tam, i;
double *yy;
int x[]={3,6,9};
double y[]={6,12,18};
int xx[]={1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10};
x_tam=3;
xx_tam=10;
yy=(double *) calloc(xx_tam,sizeof(double));

interp1(x, x_tam, y, xx, xx_tam, yy);

for(i=0;i<xx_tam;i++){
    printf("%d\t%f\n",xx[i],yy[i]);
}

}
```

And its **outcome**:

1       2.000000

2       4.000000

3       6.000000

4       8.000000

5       10.000000

6       12.000000

7       14.000000

8       16.000000

9       18.000000

10      20.000000

Answer (score 15):

I've ported Luis's code to c++. It seems to be working but I haven't checked it a lot, so be aware and re-check your results.

```
#include <vector>
#include <cfloat>
#include <math.h>

vector< float > interp1( vector< float > &x, vector< float > &y, vector< float > &x_new )
{
    vector< float > y_new;
    y_new.reserve( x_new.size() );

    std::vector< float > dx, dy, slope, intercept;
    dx.reserve( x.size() );
    dy.reserve( x.size() );
    slope.reserve( x.size() );
    intercept.reserve( x.size() );
    for( int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i ){
        if( i < x.size()-1 )
        {
            dx.push_back( x[i+1] - x[i] );
            dy.push_back( y[i+1] - y[i] );
            slope.push_back( dy[i] / dx[i] );
            intercept.push_back( y[i] - x[i] * slope[i] );
        }
        else
        {
            dx.push_back( dx[i-1] );
            dy.push_back( dy[i-1] );
            slope.push_back( slope[i-1] );
            intercept.push_back( intercept[i-1] );
        }
    }

    for ( int i = 0; i < x_new.size(); ++i ) 
    {
        int idx = findNearestNeighbourIndex( x_new[i], x );
        y_new.push_back( slope[idx] * x_new[i] + intercept[idx] );

    }

}

int findNearestNeighbourIndex( float value, vector< float > &x )
{
    float dist = FLT_MAX;
    int idx = -1;
    for ( int i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i ) {
        float newDist = value - x[i];
        if ( newDist > 0 && newDist < dist ) {
            dist = newDist;
            idx = i;
        }
    }

    return idx;
}
```

Comment: He specifically asked for a C implementation, so this is not really an appropriate answer.

Comment: This is fine as I am looking for a C++ implementation.  Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Excelent implementations of commonly used functions can be found in the book [Numerical Recipes in C](http://apps.nrbook.com/rollover/index.html), which is viewable for free online. Chapter 3.1.2 has a linear interpolation recipe, the rest of the chapter covers more advanced ones.

I can strongly recommend this book, it's very well written and covers a vast amount of algorithms, which are also implemented in a very efficient and still understandable fashion.

Answer (score 5):

There were problems with the C-Code submitted by Luis. First the encuentraValorMasProximo was missing. Second, the array reservation is one number short. I have also cleaned up the function. Below is the functional C-Code with the encuentraValorMasProximo function (renamed findNearestNeighbourIndex).

```
#include <float.h> 

int findNearestNeighbourIndex( double value, double *x, int len )
{
    double dist;
    int idx;
    int i;

    idx = -1;
    dist = DBL_MAX;
    for ( i = 0; i < len; i++ ) {
        double newDist = value - x[i];
        if ( newDist > 0 && newDist < dist ) {
            dist = newDist;
            idx = i;
        }
    }

    return idx;
}

void interp1(double *x, int x_tam, double *y, double *xx, int xx_tam, double *yy)
{
    double dx, dy, *slope, *intercept;
    int i, indiceEnVector;

    slope=(double *)calloc(x_tam,sizeof(double));
    intercept=(double *)calloc(x_tam,sizeof(double));

    for(i = 0; i < x_tam; i++){
        if(i<x_tam-1){
            dx = x[i + 1] - x[i];
            dy = y[i + 1] - y[i];
            slope[i] = dy / dx;
            intercept[i] = y[i] - x[i] * slope[i];
        }else{
            slope[i]=slope[i-1];
            intercept[i]=intercept[i-1];
        }
    }

    for (i = 0; i < xx_tam; i++) {
        indiceEnVector = findNearestNeighbourIndex( xx[i], x, x_tam);
        if (indiceEnVector != -1)
            yy[i]=slope[indiceEnVector] * xx[i] + intercept[indiceEnVector];
        else
            yy[i]=DBL_MAX;
    }
    free(slope);
    free(intercept);
}
```

Answer (score 4):

If this helps someone in the future, this is a version without temporary arrays and without the 0 bug.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <limits>
#include <cmath>


template<typename Real>
int nearestNeighbourIndex(std::vector<Real> &x, Real &value)
{
    Real dist = std::numeric_limits<Real>::max();
    Real newDist = dist;
    size_t idx = 0;

    for (size_t i = 0; i < x.size(); ++i) {
        newDist = std::abs(value - x[i]);
        if (newDist <= dist) {
            dist = newDist;
            idx = i;
        }
    }

    return idx;
}

template<typename Real>
std::vector<Real> interp1(std::vector<Real> &x, std::vector<Real> &y, std::vector<Real> &x_new)
{
    std::vector<Real> y_new;
    Real dx, dy, m, b;
    size_t x_max_idx = x.size() - 1;
    size_t x_new_size = x_new.size();

    y_new.reserve(x_new_size);

    for (size_t i = 0; i < x_new_size; ++i)
    {
        size_t idx = nearestNeighbourIndex(x, x_new[i]);

        if (x[idx] > x_new[i])
        {
            dx = idx > 0 ? (x[idx] - x[idx - 1]) : (x[idx + 1] - x[idx]);
            dy = idx > 0 ? (y[idx] - y[idx - 1]) : (y[idx + 1] - y[idx]);
        }
        else
        {
            dx = idx < x_max_idx ? (x[idx + 1] - x[idx]) : (x[idx] - x[idx - 1]);
            dy = idx < x_max_idx ? (y[idx + 1] - y[idx]) : (y[idx] - y[idx - 1]);
        }

        m = dy / dx;
        b = y[idx] - x[idx] * m;

        y_new.push_back(x_new[i] * m + b);
    }

    return y_new;
}

int main() {
    vector<float> x{1, 2, 3, 4, 5};
    vector<float> y{5, 6, 7, 8, 9};
    vector<float> newx{0, 5, 6.123, 12.123, 2, 4};

    auto res = interp1(x, y, newx);
    for (auto i: res)
        cout << i << " ";
    cout << endl;
}
```

Comment: Very helpful and easy to translate to other languages.

Answer (score 3):

@user1097111, your code exists a bug, in function findNearestNeighbourIndex, it should be if ( newDist >= 0 && newDist < dist ), not if ( newDist > 0 && newDist < dist ).

Answer (score 2):

You may look at the GSL (numerical scientific library). There are many Matlab-like functions, among them and one-dimensional interpolation.

I am on my phone now, sorry, can not provide link.

Comment: +1 because of [GSL Interpolation](http://www.gnu.org/software/gsl/manual/html_node/Interpolation.html). However, it is too heavy to be used just for one function, but it is ok as an alternative.

Answer (score 2):

Are you aware of the [Matlab Coder](http://www.mathworks.com/products/matlab-coder/)?  It automatically generates c/c++ code from Matlab code.  If you have that as part of your Matlab package, you could just run the interp1 function through it and see what Matlab spits out.

Comment: I have tried it, but it is illegible.

Answer (score 1):

see lininterp1f in fileexchange.